# Implement multiple relationship using core data

Tags: iphone, core-data

[image: The ER diagram]

Here above shows the ER-Diagram.

It's easy to implement to-many binary relationship using core data. But it confuse me how to implement this kind of multiple relationship.

Hope that someone could give a hand.

Comment: Whats the question here? Each student is enrolled in a unique Course/TA pair, right?

Comment: (Students, Courses) and TAs form a to-many relationships

Comment: @JackieLam: Did my answer help? Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understood your problem correctly, but wouldn't two
one-to-many relationships (from Course to TA and from Student to TA) describe
your model? Each TA has exactly one Student and one Course, but each Student and
each Course can be related to many TAs.

[image]

Comment: I agree with you. +1. I would rename `tas` in `courseToTas` and `studentToTas`. Just for making them explicit. But this is only my opinion ;)

Comment: @flexaddicted: Thanks! I normally use the plain lowercase entity name for relationships (in the plural form to to-many relationships), but that is really a matter of taste.